# why is my javascript not running/mail not sending?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, submit

pretty much a newbie to all this so trying to keep my code as simple as possible. I have a form which will send me an email once submitted although I want the user to have to fill in all fields before submitting, therefore I have the following script

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $('#mailform').submit(function()    {
        if (('#emailName' || '#emailEmail' || '#emailSubject').val() == "") {
            alert('Please fill out all fields before clicking submit');
            return false;
        }
        else    {
            alert('Your Email has been sent');
        }
    });
    </script>
```

This is my HTML

```
<form id="mailform" method="" action="http://www.mysiteaddress.co.uk/sendmail.php">
                    Your Name: <input id="emailName" name="yourName" type="text" /><br />
                    Your Email:  <input id="emailEmail" name="yourEmail" type="text" /><br />
                    Subject:     <input id="emailSubject" name="subject" type="text" /><br />
                    Message:<br />
                    <textarea name="message" rows="15" cols="40"></textarea><br />
                    <input type="submit" />
                </form>
```

However when I click submit the form completely ignores the javascript and runs the php. Why is my javascript not running first?

Validation is now working however now when it runs my php it doesnt mail me the form and instead jumps straight to the header part of my else statement

```
if ( preg_match( "/[\r\n]/", $name ) || preg_match( "/[\r\n]/", $email ) ) {

header ( "Location: http://www.mysite.co.uk/contactme" );

}
else    {
        mail( "me@mysite.co.uk", "$name <$subject>",
            $message, "From: $name <$email>" );
        header ( "Location: http://www.mysite.co.uk/contactme" );
}
```

?>

Comment: Is your JavaScript in the `<head>`? If so, that's the problem. Try moving your whole `<script>` block to the very end of the `<body>` (right before `</body>`).

Comment: try using $(document).ready(function() { $("#mailform#").submit...});

Comment: Notwithstanding other issues, your selector for finding the fields' values looks very wrong to me. You need three separate jQuery val() calls.

Comment: @seanRoss see my answer, Please omit the form action and sends the data to be pass through a `.post` method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are validating the input via JavaScript, then, be aware that once JavaScript is disabled, your validation is completely bypassed. 
To prevent such thing from happening (as well as resolve your issue), here is what you can do: 
 
**Step 1:** Don't use **<input type="submit" />**; rather, use **<input type="button" />**. What this does is that it prevents your form from being submitted at all without JavaScript. So, the user is forced to turn on JavaScript; hence, the validation can now work. However, be sure to notify the users that JavaScript is required. You can simply use the **noscript** tag for that. 
 
**Step 2:** Now, to fix your issue; give your button an id and define an **onclick** event. Here is an example of what to put in it:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function()    {   
    $('#button_id').click(function()    {
        if ($('#emailName').val()=="" || $('#emailEmail').val()==""
            || $('#emailSubject').val() == ""){
            alert('Please fill out all fields before clicking submit');
        }
        else    {
            alert('Your Email will be submitted now');
            $("#mailform").submit();      
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

This should resolve your issue. 
 
Hope the explanation is clear and this helps.

Comment: by using a button instead of submit it now seems to run nothing at all when i click the button

Comment: @SeanRoss You have to give the button an **id** and the **id** must be the same as the one in the function; in my example, I used **#button_id**

Comment: again this seems to be working in jsFiddle but not on my site

Comment: actually it was my script src that was wrong, sorry, but now once it runs the javascript and submits the form, it is running the php but not mailing me for some reason

Comment: my validatin issue is now resolved but it is not mailing me the form, i'll edit my question to show my php

Comment: That is a separate issue which has nothing to do with JavaScript. You mind need to update the title also, though you might be prepared for some nasty comments, especially since the original problem has been resolved.

Comment: You can create a separate question, search around the web, or come into the PHP chatroom, though I doubt you'll be able to talk in there.

Answer (score 2):

The selectors in your `if` statement are problematic.

`TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function`
`(evaluating '('#emailName' || '#emailEmail' || '#emailSubject').val()')`

Try this:

```
if ($('#emailName').val()==""
  || $('#emailEmail').val()==""
  || $('#emailSubject').val() == ""
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rPDnQ/

Comment: using jsFiddle my script seems to work fine so I think it may have something to do with where my script is actually positioned, I have tried it both in the and just before the but neither seem to make my script run before going to the php

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete the form action and use jquery `.post` method to send the data to which your form action would do, and validate also your inputs not what you do, so you might say:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type = "text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() { 
      //get your inputs
      var name = $('#emailName').val();
      var email = $('#emailEmail').val();
      var subject = $('#emailSubject').val();


      //validate it so
      if(name == '' || email == '' || subject == '') { 
          //do something
      } else { 
         //do your `ajax` call or `.post` request here like
          $.post('urlToExecuteSendMail', { name: name, email: email, subject: subject }, function(data) { 
              alert(data);
         });
      }
  });
</script>
```